# Gallery setSelection does not fires image selector

Tags: android, gallery, imageview

I have gallery widget, when you scroll it, currently selected image has border - just simple selector, like this

```
<selector
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item
    android:state_selected="true"
    android:drawable="@drawable/thumbnail_frame" />
<item
    android:drawable="@android:color/transparent" />
```

and in gallery adapter's getView its attached like this

```
image.setBackgroundDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.xxx));
```

The problem is, when I change gallery selection with setSelection(), the selected item doesn't have a border. But when I just scroll it with finger border on selected item works OK. I think, setSelection() does not fire setSelected() or something like this.

I suppose, the solution would be to call setSelected() alongside setSelection(), but how do I call it for currently selected ImageView? Or is there some other way of doing this?

Comment: You should statically assign the background to your adapter view (in the layout).  It may be your code that sets the background is happening too late to "see" the selected state.  I have also had issues if the adapter view going into the gallery is not focusable; you may want to add states for that into your selector as well.  Did you try your suggestion, and did it work?  You can always examine the source code of `Gallery.setSelection()` for reference!

Comment: just a comment to your code, image.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.xxx) is simpler than image.setBackgroundDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.xxx))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a ViewPager and setCurrentItem. They work much better.

Comment: Well, yeah now I can use it, but it was not available at time of post.